Embassy flagging
If someone gets flagged by the indian embassy abroad would he or she be stopped at every country's immigration and questioned? What about being able to get a tourist visa for any country? Would that be an issue too?

Flagged how exactly, and why? This question is too vague to be answerable.

You keep using the word “flagged“ without ever answering request for details. You once alluded to some fake documents, is that what you are concerned about? Speculating about some unspecified “flag” is not useful…

No. Generally speaking, countries don't talk to each other, they have no access to each others' immigration data.
Some exceptions:

Some alliances (eg Five Eyes) and unions (notably the EU) do routinely share data. As far as I know, though, India is not party to any of these.
There's physical evidence of being refused entry/deported/banned from a county stamped into your passport. Based on your other questions, you're an Indian citizen, so Indian authorities can't do this you.
There's an Interpol international arrest warrant out for you. This only happens for serious crimes and it's done by the police, not immigration.


I have heard if ur passport is flagged u cant even cross the immigration of the country u reside in?

in addition to the forms of cooperation you list, there is also an internationally distributed list of canceled passports referenced by many countries, but the question asked here does not give us nearly enough information to know if it is relevant to the situation at hand

@Mohd Where did you hear that? And what exactly do you mean by ‘flagged’?

Flagging is like a red mark on someone's passport i guess

@Mohd You asked the question, why do you need to guess? Surely if someone had written something in red ink on your passport you would see it. Otherwise, explain what you mean concretely, without metaphor.
